# Troubleshoot the following error in spark streaming

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am getting this error when I try to write data to HDFS. The job works fine and I am getting this error. So clearly there is a data issue.

```
18/09/15 04:13:43 ERROR JobScheduler: Error running job streaming job 1536977640000 ms.0
java.util.NoSuchElementException: None.get
    at scala.None$.get(Option.scala:347)
    at scala.None$.get(Option.scala:345)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommand$class.metrics(DataWritingCommand.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.metrics$lzycompute(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:46)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.metrics(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:46)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.metrics$lzycompute(commands.scala:100)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.metrics(commands.scala:100)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlanInfo$.fromSparkPlan(SparkPlanInfo.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:654)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:273)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:267)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:225)
```

Does this mean my output is having None in the DStream? The following is the code I have for writing DStream to HDFS

```scala
outputDStream.repartition(100).foreachRDD((rdd: RDD[Transaction], time: SparkTime) => {
      val df = rdd.toDF

      val dfWithTimestamp = df.select("*").withColumn("current_timestamp",current_timestamp())

      dfWithTimestamp.write
          .mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
          .save(s"${outputPath}")

    })
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I am sorry it is not the same, because I am getting the error after approximately 12 hours of data being written.